# How does communication between a BeagleBoneBlack occur and what is special about its mounting procedure?

Tags: linux, network-interface, route

If a BeagleBone is connected to a linux machine (and *probably* also to Windows in some form) it will identify itself somehow as a network interface card and, consequentially, will be assigned an ip-address (and routing table entry) by the local network manager.

As you can see [here](http://beagleboard.org/getting-started), the final step for verification of a proper boot is being able to connect to its web-server.

First, how does it work? What is special about the mounting process that the network manager creates a new interface for it?

I am having a rather difficult time finding information on this topic and am not sure what search terms are most appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.linux-usb.org/gadget/

The port itself is configured as OTG, that is it can act as either master or slave on the usb connection. There is a kernel driver USB Gadget that lets your OTG chipset act like/emulate various slave devices in a standardized way.

Comment: Interesting. So the kernel driver allows emulation of a NIC, then, in this case? When plugged in, the BeagleBone comes up as `usb0` in linux interfaces.